# T-SQL calculate with calendar week

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a T-SQL question - I'm using SQL-Server 2012:

I have a varchar **calendar week column** (1-52). In my where clause I only want to select the last **6 weeks** going back from the current calendar week of the current year. I also have a year varchar column with values of "2011" , "2012" and "2013".

But now I'm struggling to set the expression for the where clause.

Or do I need a Having clause to get this done?

I've tried it like this:

```
Having Calendarweek BETWEEN max(Calendarweek)-6 AND max(Calendarweek) AND Year=2013
```

but it returns all weeks.

Hope you can help me out with this.
thank you.

Comment: Why are you storing numerical values (weeknumber, yearnumber) in a varchar column? That makes these sort of calculations difficult/slow

Comment: that's what they gave me to work with :-) I'm thinking about converting them.

Comment: If you select `max(Calendarweek)` you will see that it returns '9' because you store numbers as strings. Comparation rules are different.

Comment: you are right - I did a tinyint conversion too but I still couldn't set the right period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
where Year ='2013'
and CAST(Calendarweek AS INT) >= datepart(week,getdate())-6
```

Comment: hello, this also returns all 10 weeks. I had to add the Calendarweek in the Group by stmt.

Comment: this works but let's say my latest entries are from week 9 - I would lose a week when going back.

Comment: Please decide if you want to filter YOUR data or just print out last six weeks ..

Comment: Since I have to add this to a view for other users as well I think your answer will work - for now ;-)